# Python Requests Explicitly Setting Headers Causes 400 Response

Tags: python, header, response

I am attempting to make a POST to a web server. I have data that I want to post in the body and headers (taken directly from Chrome). Without going into too many details, when I explicitly set headers, I get a 400 response code.

```
# Explicitly set headers causes 400 response    
req = requests.post(url, auth_form, headers=authenticate)
print(req.status_code)
```

But the following returns a 200 response code:

```
# Setting data as my form to post and headers as json
# Returns a 200 response code    
req = requests.post(url, auth_form, authenticate)
print(req.status_code)
```

I am attempting to simulate a login through code. Even when I receive the 200 response I do not successfully login. I suspect this is because I am not properly setting the headers, but I am unsure.

I am actually able to remove the headers entirely (as either headers= or json) and still receive a 200 response code. I believe this reinforces the idea that the headers are not being set properly.

```
# Removing headers entirely 
# Returns a 200 response code    
req = requests.post(url, auth_form)
print(req.status_code)
```

I am not sure if additional details (such as what some of the headers are) will be necessary. If so, I will provide as much of that information as I can.

Edit: Headers, as requested:

```
    authenticate = {}
    authenticate["Accept"] = accept
    authenticate["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate, br"
    authenticate["Accept-Language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.8"
    authenticate["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=0"
    authenticate["Connection"] = "keep-alive"
    authenticate["Host"] = dns + ":" + str(port)
    authenticate["Origin"] = "http://" + dns + ":" + str(port)
    authenticate["Referer"] = "http://" + dns + ":" + str(port) + "/eproc/"
    authenticate["Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"] = upgrade_insecure
    authenticate["Cookie"] = "ID=" + self.session_id
    authenticate["User-Agent"] = user_agent

    auth_form = {}
    auth_form["username"] = username
    auth_form["password"] = password
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're passing authenticate as a json in the second attempt. To quote the docstring: ":param json: (optional) json data to send in the body of the :class:`Request`." Anyways, yes, it looks like your request is malformed, but w/o information on what your header looks like (or even the entire request), there's not much left to do.

Comment: Hi Hendrik. Thank you for your response. You're absolutely right that the second attempt makes no sense. I believe the first one should work, but it does not. I have done an actual login to the site using Chrome and grabbed the headers from there. I will update the original post with those headers. The "auth_form" that I am posting is a dictionary with the expected username and password.